# Wilsonian RGE: Problem 23.7 in the textbook, M.D. Schwartz's ''QFT and Standard Model''

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Can anyone give me some hints or directions to work out the solution to the following problem?
[image]

This problem is from chapter 23 of the textbook written by Professor Schwartz. I can't figure out neither how this formula comes out nor why the first term corresponds to tree and the second term corresponds to loop.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.